# Can not update a system app

Tags: android, google-play

I have a application preloaded on ROM, and put it on system app. Current version code is 3. This apk also published on Google Play.

Note : All cases below I use same key store, same package with the apk preloaded on ROM.

*** From Android Studio, I build a new version and upgrade version code to 4.**

**Case 1:**

I copy this apk to phone and install manually. Phone display "Can not install". I check the log and it show :

*"W/PackageManager: Package xxx signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!"*

**Case 2:**

I uploaded the new apk to Google Play. Google Play accept it normally. After Google approved and published the app, I open Google Play app , find my app and check the status. It displayed "UnInstalled" and "Open".( It should display "Update" but it did not).

Right now I can not update my application. Can anybody tell me what is the reason for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the checklist to update app-

1. Update will come only if you already have that app installed in
   phone as `PackageManager` checks for that package if it is not same it
   will `install` as new app(not update).
2. It has to be signed with same key which was used to sign system
   app when it was preloaded in ROM.
3. Version Code has to be increased.